# ProFTPD quotas limit and tally differences

Tags: proftpd

I'm trying to understand what are the differences between limit and tally quotas in proftpd and I can't really see them. Both seem to be similar and also with same parameters. I would apreciate any help or example to understand this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "limits" in ProFTPD's mod_quotatab module refer to the *maximum values*, whereas the "tallies" are the *current* values.

For example, you might configure a maximum of 5 uploads (a limit).  And so far, the user in question might have only done 3 uploads (the tally).

The mod_quotatab [documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab.html#Usage) attempts to describe these as well.  Perhaps there are ways to describe these better?